# Apache and Rewrite Module

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I created a file .htaccess in the */var/www* directory. The rights are "root root --wxrwxrwxr".

The content of the file is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ testphp.php
```

When I call the page phpinfo.php, I've got: Loaded Modules  ... mod_rewrite ...
Therefore, the modules is loaded.

After each modification, I restared the server manually with sudo `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

The error.log gives

> Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

When I call a page anyone.htm or anyone.php, the rewrite.log does contain nothing and the real page is called. If I understand, the page `anyone.php` should be replaced by `testphp.php`

Did I make siomething wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i were a web server, i'd ignore any config file that was world writable, for stability and security's sakes.  I know there's places in Apache that do exactly that; i forget whether .htaccess processing is one of those places, but i'd assume/hope it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

I changed the files rights to 644 and directory to 755.
I restart the Apache server and I've got exactly the same result.

Comment: If you can afford to do so, add a line of garbage to .htaccess for a minute and make sure it causes a server error.  It won't take down the server; it'll just break access to that directory and everything inside.   But it's the quickest way i know of (short of rooting through the config files) to make sure your .htaccess file is actually getting used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help

Here is what I made to get the Apache2 server running with the Rewrite Rule:

1. I re-installed the server from a new hard disk
2. I activated the Rewrite with 'sudo a2enmod rewrite'
3. I created the file '.htaccess' with the rules:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRules ^(.*)$ test.php
   ```

In the "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default", I added in the directory/

```
AllowOverride all
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

and in the directory "/var/www", the same 2 lines. I don't know why, but the rules `RewriteLog n` does not word in the .htaccess. In the "/var/www", I created 2 files, index.html (the default) and test.php. The test.php contains

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

When I call the page index.html, the php info is displayed

One more time, thanks.